# How can I get Icon from Unicode in fontAwesomeIcons?

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, font-awesome

I wanna get "FontAwesomeIcons.airFreshener" and I´ve got his Unicode number ("f5d0"). Is there a way of get the icon? At least get "airFreshener".

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding towards the problem, please try the below piece of code to get the icon from the FontAwesome library in Flutter.

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new IconButton(
     // Use the FontAwesomeIcons class for the IconData
       icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.air-freshener), 
       onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
    );
  }
}
```

Once you try the above solution, please let me know. If you face any difficulties, if it solve your problem, please like my answer as useful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is possible, but it's not the recommended way to use FontAwesome in Flutter. Try using the [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) package instead:

```dart
Container(
  child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.airFreshener),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use syntax to display unicode,

for example:

```
   ....
    const TextForm(
    errorText: '\u24D8 Error text',
     )

   ...
```

Will display next
[image]